# Optimising Java compilation? Maven build?

Tags: java, maven, optimization, compilation, javac

Most search with these keywords give results about the Java compiler optimising the resulting byte code and all revolving around the resulting program performance and whatnot.

My question is actually: is there tuning one can do on javac to optimise the very compilation process? I don't know, how is the whole thing threaded? are all cores of CPU used?

Also, most of my work is built with Maven. Are there some other Maven-bound tweaks to do to improve build speed?

Comment: First: How many code (lines of code based on SonarQube?) ? How long does your build take? Which Maven version do you use? Are you using most up-to-date plugins? Have you measured if it is really the problem of compiling?

Comment: Speeding up the compilation can also be made by switching to ECJ compiler, see here for a sample configuration: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/FAQ#Can_I_use_the_Tycho_compiler_support_in_non-OSGi_projects.2C_too.3F

Comment: You are talking about the Eclipse JDT compiler. But just using it will not improve performance of your compilation.